# CoolLightBox multiple galeries vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lightbox

i want to set up page with multiple galleries with CoolLightBox, when i have one gallery it worked for me but when i want to create multiple....for every image on page single galery....it is only showing me one image in lightbox

here is my code:

```
<div class="m-3" v-for="(item, imageIndex) in info" :key="item.id">
    <div class="row mt-3">
      
      <div id="burza" class="col-lg-3 my-auto text-center">

        <CoolLightBox
          :items="['localhost:4000/api/uploads/' + item.image]"
          :index="index"
          @close="index = null">
        </CoolLightBox>


        {{imageIndex}} // here is index of every image on page but it still didnt work...
        <div class="text-center">
          <img
              class="img-thumbnail"
              :key="imageIndex"
              @click="index = imageIndex"
              :src= "'localhost:4000/api/uploads/' + item.image">
        </div>
        <a :href="'localhost:4000/api/uploads/' + item.image"><img class="img-fluid" :src="'localhost:4000/api/uploads/' + item.image"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

how to create multiple CoolLightBox galleries? i think that my problem is with imageIndex but i don´t know how to improve it...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by updating the images array during the click event. So you actually have the CoolLightBox outside the for each loop like this:

```
<div>
    <CoolLightBox
      :items="images"
      :index="index"
      @close="index = null">
    </CoolLightBox>

    <div>
      <div class="collections-container"
            v-for="(collection, collectionIndex) in collections"
            @click="images=collection.images, index = 0"
            :key="collectionIndex">

          <div
            :style="{ 'background': 'url(' + collection.cover + ') no-repeat center', 'background-size': 'cover' }"
          ></div>

      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        index: null,
        images: this.collections[0].images
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

So what you're doing here, is keeping the lightbox outside the for loop and if you see the scripts section, the images variable initially has the first collections's image set by default.

Inside the for loop, I'm rendering the collection with it's cover image and when clicked, I'm setting the images variable to the clicked collections's image set and then setting index as 0 (since I always want the collection to open with the first item). Hope this helps. You can see this in action at [this link](https://thamu.in/collections).